# Lobry de Bruyn-Van Ekenstein reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I've recently read about this reaction called Lobry de Bruyn-Van Ekenstein reaction, where simple glucose is converted to fructose and mannose by adding a base or acid, as I've read this is supposedly called Base/Acid catalyzed isomerization but I wasn't able to find any reaction mechanism for the reaction.

[image]

A very similar reaction I've seen in synthesis of vanillin from eugenol where eugenol is converted to isoeugenol by using $\ce{KOH}$ as base and it stated that it was base catalyzed isomerization but there wasn't any mechanism mentioned.

[image]

I would like to know the mechanism for this base catalyzed isomerization reaction. Any help would be great!

Comment: That's a fancy name for what's essentially keto-enol tautomerisation. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/22%3A_Carbonyl_Alpha-Substitution_Reactions/22.01%3A_Keto-Enol_Tautomerism read until the bottom as it explains the isomerisation of your alpha-hydroxy carbonyl compound. The eugenol one is not so easily explained.

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm unable to understand how eugenol to isoeugenol is a base catalysed isomerisation?

Comment: A quick search of Google Sholar shows that this named reaction is pretty common, but what a mouthful!

Comment: Have you went through Wikipedia? Also, you need to capitalize the names of the discoverers. I have done that for you.

Comment: @NilayGhosh thanks for the edit! yes I've gone through Wikipedia but I still did not manage to understand the mechanism for eugenol to isoeugenol conversion even if base catalyzed isomerization means simple keto enol tautomerism if base or acid just activates the mechanism for keto enol tautomerism, I don't understand how the second reaction occurs.

Comment: also the reaction has been carried out successfully I've seen a person on YouTube carried out the exact same synthesis but he did not mention the mechanism of the reaction and many sources just say its a base catalyzed isomerization type reaction but they did not provide any mechanism for that.

Comment: Did you Google "mechanism eugenol isoeugenol" and look at Images?